# How to Hide/Resize views in UITableCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

In my Table Cell, I have two views, brownView and blueView. I have set the constraints such that the size of my cell depends upon the height of these two respective views. Now, I want the height of the TableCell to dynamically be set such that, if I hide the brownView, only the blueView must fill the TableCell. And if I hide the blueView, only the brownView must fill the cell.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5XP3.jpg

There were two approaches I took:

1) Add these two views to a stackView but it equalises the sizes of the blueView and brownView which is not what I want.

2) Make one of the views 'hidden'. But this just leaves a big white gap where the View is Hidden instead of automatically reducing the size of the TableCell.

How should I go about this?

My TableCellCode:

```
class ExploreTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var blueView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var brownView: UIView!

    var exploreArt: ExploreArtist!
    {
        didSet
        {

            blueView.isHidden = true

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can set the height of blue view to 0
make outlet of blue view's height

cell.blueViewHeigt.constant = 0

and you want blue view bigger then

cell.blueViewHeigt.constant = 40(or whatever)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? blueViewHeight is not a valid function. I've edited the code to show my TableCell code. Could you please tell me more?

Comment: you can change the height of your view :- blueView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height : 0)

alternate -> you can make the outlet of you height constraint and can change the height with that heightContraint outlet
heightConstraint.constant = 0

Comment: But you've given the answer in absolute terms. What if I want the Width to Match that of the Parent View?

Comment: then you can change height by changing constraint 
or give width -> self.view.frame.size.width